# Is the function of curve's length continuous?

Tags: calculus

When I study the curve integral, I find an interesting problem. There is a curve defined as a continuous function $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, the length of $\gamma$ is defined as
$$l(\gamma,a,b)=\sup \!
\left\{
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} d(\gamma(t_{i}),\gamma(t_{i - 1})) ~ \Bigg| ~ n \in \mathbb{N} ~ \text{and} ~ a = t_{0} < t_{1} < \ldots < t_{n} = b
\right\},$$
where $d(x,y)$ is the distance between $x$ and $y$.

Assume $\gamma$ is rectifiable, which means $l(\gamma,a,b)$ is finite. Now I define a function, $f(x):=l(\gamma,a,x)$,where $x\in[a,b]$.

The question is that whether I can conclude $f$ is continuous. My way is to prove that for any $\epsilon$, there exists $\delta$ that when
$0<x-x_0<\delta$,$$0<f(x)-f(x_0)<\epsilon.$$ The first inequality is easy to prove. I am stucking in the second inequality, which make me doubt that the proposition is actually false.

Comment: What I mean is $\gamma$ is continuous. I have corrected.

Comment: What happens when you try to prove $l$ is continuous?  Your formulation "$l(\gamma,t_{i-1},t_i)\rightarrow0$ when $|t_i-t_{i-1}|\rightarrow 0$" seems to be more than "continuous" and more like "uniformly continuous".

Comment: I have corrected once more. Forget about it, just focus on the continuity of $f$:P

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered. The link is following:
[Showing that a curve is not rectifiable if its arc length is not a continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/124244).